# how to return eloquent query result after save in API - Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-passport

when I am using the eloquent model to return result I got an error that `Keypath "file://C:\xampp\htdocs\apis\storage\oauth-public.key" does not exist or is not readable` but when I used raw query I got required results. My question is how I can use the model to return results. 
Here is my code:

It is working

```
return OrderItem::find(21);
```

It is not working

```
$order_item = OrderItem::find(21);
$order_item->quantity = 24;
$order_item->save();
return $order_item;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to upgrade Passport to `3.0.*` and see what happens

Comment: I am still wondering how this question relates to Passport. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

run the command in the root directory of the project

```
php artisan passport:install
```

code for Laravel 5.4.24 - Laravel 6.0

```
$order_item = OrderItem::find(21);
$order_item->quantity = 24;
$order_item->save();

$order_item->refresh();

return $order_item;
```

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: The operating system is windows